# Equivalent of session_start() and $_SESSION in Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am trying to find the equivalent of session_start() and $_SESSION in Node.js/Express in order to put the id of the current user in the session. Almost every video/tutorial uses express-session but I read that :

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is
>   purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak
>   memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process,
>   and is meant for debugging and developing.

Do I need a certain module to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You should connect `express-session` to a database in which it can store sessions. There's a list of compatible session stores in the documentation: https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores

Using MongoDB is a popular choice (https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo) but you could use any modules in the list above.

Comment: I'm currently using MySQL for my database, but like I said in the post, I read that express-session is not designed for a production enviroment.

Comment: No, the default configuration of express-session isn't for production environments. By default express-session just stores sessions in memory.  You should be storing your sessions in MySQL. So use `express-mysql-session` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session) with `express-session`. That will work great for production.

Comment: So the warning you see is just saying "Hey, you should be using something from this list with express-session: https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores"